# Count with condition XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling to make a counter with conditions. My XML is:

```
<comments>
    <comment>
        <name>Jonh</name>
        <num>4/7</num>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <name>Mary</name>
        <num>2/9</num>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <name>Catie</name>
        <num>12/2</num>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <name>Stefen</name>
        <num>127/300</num>
    </comment>
</comments>
```

The tag  has the following structure:

```
number1/number2
```

And I want to know how often the number1 is greater than the number2 in all tags

I've tried with count:

```
count(tokenize(//comment/num, '/')[1] &gt; tokenize(//comment/num, '/')[2])
```

But no results. I thought about using a variable as an counter but they are immutable. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring-before` and `substring-after` to calculate those values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        number1 is greater than the number2
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//num[substring-before(.,'/') &gt; substring-after(.,'/')])" /> times.
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there as it is, the trick is that you need to move the gt check to a predicate

```
count(//comment/num[tokenize(., '/')[1] &gt; tokenize(., '/')[2]])
```

to select out the `num` elements you're interested and then count those.

Comment: Hum I tried using a variable like this: "<xsl:variable name="num1GreaterThanNum2" select="count(//comment/num[tokenize(., '/')[1] &gt; tokenize(., '/')[2]])"/>" but does not return a result!

Comment: @JohnSoart are you sure your processor supports XSLT 2.0 rather than just 1.0? The `tokenize` function is not available in 1.0 but as suggested in the other answer you could use `substring-before(., '/')` and `substring-after(., '/')` instead of the `tokenize(...)[1]` and `[2]`.